# How to verify Chrome extension identity. (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-app

I'm working on some browser (chrome, firefox) extension. This chrome extension will have it's own backend and user authentication.

Is there any good way to verify identity of this extension?
So for example I would like to identify if request is made from my extension, if not I would like to through an error or redirect somewhere else.

Comment: If it is making http requests there is little security

Comment: I understand that. I was thinking about some token for example that google may provide so I can validate it on my backend or something like this. Something like oauth 2.0 for rest api but in this case it would be double protection first for chrome extension second for the rest api).

Comment: What do you mean with "the identity of the extension"? Your extension is open source, so that's not something you can verify: everything your extension can do can be reproduced with cURL and other tools like it. So in terms of true security, you're looking solely at user accounts and auth tokens that you can store locally for use in your API calls.